# array required, but List<Double> found error

Tags: java

So I have these Lists:

```
List<Double> myDoubList1 = new LinkedList<>();
myDoubList1.Add(100);
myDoubList1.Add(66.7);

List<Double> myDoubList=new LinkedList<>();
myDoubList.Add(3);

double g=myDoubList[0]*myDoubList1[0];//error
```

But at the last line, it has an error:array required, but List found error.

Why is it giving me this error?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html You'll find what you need. Take a look at the get method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot access lists with the bracket notation. List elements must be adressed via [`List#get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) instead:

```
myDoubleList1.get(0);
```

Comment: Also there is no such a thing `Add`. Should be [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not `Add`, its `add`. 
Second: You need to use the `get` method:

```
double d=list1.get(0)*list2.get(0);
```